# array_push mysqli $row return the same data

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I have a data base return array as such

```
$row['id']=1, $row['col1']='col1', $row['col2']=col2
```

when i push each $row to $result

```
array_push($result, $row);
```

the $row is overwritten b/c they share the same key. I can't get my mind around it.  but if it is overwritten, when I var_dump($result) it should output only one set, instead it output multiple row with the same set of data, please help.

Comment: Well as the code above stands, you're pushing the whole $row array to the $result array...

Comment: Did you read the manual? `array_push() treats array as a stack, and pushes the passed variables onto the end of array. The length of array increases by the number of variables pushed.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace this: `array_push($result, $row);` 
with this:

```
foreach($row AS $current_row)
{
   array_push($result, $current_row);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure to understand.
If you want to add `$row` in `$result`, you can use `array_merge()` function like this:

```
$result = array_merge($result, $row);
```

Comment: this works too but @milk's allow better array structure. thanks

Comment: Thank's for your return and the up vote. :) Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

array_push adds elements to 2 or more dimension array. Before using it you must define an array. Use this:

```
$result = array();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch())
{
   array_push($result, $row);
}
```